# How define & Execute Powershell Functions from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to create a powershell function and use it from inside the C#

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;
namespace PowerShell_eg
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var psFunction = @" function Get-Hostname { hostname } ";

            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);    
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            ??// HOW TO Add Get-Hostname & INVOKE IT ??

            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(psFunction);
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Get-Hostname");
            var results = pipeline.Invoke();
            foreach (var obj in results.Where(o => o != null))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I get CommandNotFound exception @ Invoke. 
The term 'Get-Hostname' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Please advice how to correctly do this!

Also it will be ideal if I can add multiple functions and cont. to use them over the life of the powershell session without having to add them again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This C# code seems to work fine for me. Just add a reference to the `System.Management.Automation` .NET assembly.

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PowerShellTest02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string func = @"function Test { Write-Host 'hello' };";
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript(func);
            ps.Invoke();
            ps.AddCommand("Test");
            ps.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully executed function");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but when I provide `string func='ps1 file path` it shows error that the term Test is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again